# Restore ZFS Pool and storage data after a system re-install

Tags: system-installation, zfs, restore

I recently re-installed my host OS to Mint 19 64 bit, and am now trying to get all of my external drives back online.

I had a ZFS storage pool made up of 4 x 1 TB disks, and set them to allow 1 drive to fail without losing data in my pool.

Now, I want to get that Storage pool back up and running.

My pool is simply called ZStore.  How can I get the drives and pool back up and accessible in my Linux system?

**EDIT**:

I did the following:

```
# sudo zpool import
   pool: ZStore1
     id: 6113527918687515983
  state: ONLINE
 status: Some supported features are not enabled on the pool.
 action: The pool can be imported using its name or numeric identifier, though
    some features will not be available without an explicit 'zpool upgrade'.
 config:

    ZStore1                                          ONLINE
      raidz1-0                                       ONLINE
        usb-WDC_WD75_02ABYS-18A6B0_152D00539000-0:0  ONLINE
        usb-WDC_WD75_02ABYS-18A6B0_152D00539000-0:1  ONLINE
        usb-WDC_WD75_02ABYS-18A6B0_152D00539000-0:2  ONLINE
        usb-WDC_WD75_02ABYS-18A6B0_152D00539000-0:3  ONLINE
```

But when I try `zpool status` or `sudo zpool status` I get

```
no pools available
```

Not sure what's going on.  The pool shows online when I import, and all drives show online, but not getting anything with status check.

tried

```
$ zpool online
```

then

```
$ zpool online ZStore1
```

then get `missing device name`, so I'm at a loss - again.

Comment: I know this is already answered below, but just to explain what you saw: the problem is that “zpool import pool” means “import the pool named ‘pool’”. ZFS is telling you it found a pool named ‘ZStore’, but no pool named ‘pool’.

Comment: Thanks @Dan That helped. I was totally misunderstanding. Storage pool is back and showing up properly now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the disks are recognized from your OS the command:

```
zpool import
```

should be enough to get the pool imported and visible in your current OS. You can check the status with command

```
zpool status
```

You can try to import it explicitly by name

```
zpool import ZStore
```

P.S. Do not forget to set the pool online:

```
zpool online
```

You can check [zpool-features](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/zpool-features.5.html) features and if they are enabled or not in your case. Seems like `zfs` build in your case is new than the version which create it. The problem is if you update you will be able to mount only with same or upper version of `zfs`

What I can recommend you is to try (if available) with live version (but this with which you create the pool)

Comment: I added a little edit @Romeo Ninov So any help is appreciated.

Comment: @bmcgonag, please check my edited answer

Comment: ok, tried upgrade and got:

`sudo zpool upgrade -a`
 
`This system supports ZFS pool feature flags.`

`All pools are already formatted using feature flags.`

`Every feature flags pool already has all supported features enabled`

Comment: I hate to do this, but I'm hitting the same issue as before.  I recall the comment about zfs being newer version than what the pool was created with, but what's the solution to that issue?  I can't figure out how to tell what version of zfs I'm running now, much less the version the zpool was created with.

Answer (score 0):

In case the automatic `zpool import ZStore1` doesn't do anything, you can try manually importing all member partitions, optionally with read-only attribute `-o readonly=on`, e.g.:

```
zpool import -f -d /dev/sda3 -f -d /dev/sdb3 -f -d /dev/sdc3 -f -d /dev/sdd3 -o readonly=on ZStore1
```